# Ĉu TEC ankoraŭ vivas?

Tags: terminology, organizations, uea

Ĉu la Terminologia Esperanto-Centro (TEC, [vidu vikipedio](https://eo.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminologia_Esperanto-Centro)) ankoraŭ aktivas?

La [ĉefpaĝo](http://esperanto.net/tec/index.html) de ĝia retejo http://esperanto.net/tec/ diras, ke tiu ĉefpaĝo laste ŝanĝiĝis 2017-04-23, do antaŭ pli ol du jaroj. Aliaj paĝoj de la retejo estas eĉ pli malnovaj.

---

Is the Terminologia Esperanto-Centro (Terminological Esperanto Center; TEC, [see Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminologia_Esperanto-Centro)) still active?

The [main page](http://esperanto.net/tec/index.html) of its website http://esperanto.net/tec/ claims to have last been changed on 2017-04-23, so more than two years ago. Other pages of the website claim to have even older last modification dates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Orlando Raola, la [nuna UEA-a estrarano respondeca pri terminologio](https://uea.org/aktuale/komunikoj/2019/La-nova-Estraro-de-UEA-dividis-siajn-taskojn-Duncan-Charters-prezidas) respondis al mi per tujmesaĝilo tiel:

> TEC nur ekzistas nun teorie, ĉar la ĉefaj aktivuloj kiuj kontribuis aŭ forpasis aŭ ne plu aktivas.

Li plue skribis, ke li

> havas proponon okupiĝi pri ekologia/mediprotekta terminaro en la Faklingva Sekcio de la Akademio de Esperanto, sed tute bone la temo povus esti ankaŭ diskutita de homoj ekster la Akademio, en eventuale nova Terminologia Fakgrupo de UEA...

kaj demandis ĉu mi

> kredas, ke troveblas sufiĉe da interesitoj inter la telegramanoj por starigi Terminologian grupon[.]